# @InjectMocks injects new Instance instead of using defined Mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have a test where a repository mock should be inserted via DI in service and somehow Mockito makes new instance and injects wrong mock into service.
My Repository class looks as followed:

```java
@Repository 
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Vorgang, Long> {
   Optional<SomeClass> findById(Long id);
}
```

Service class:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
   

    private final SomeRepository someRepository;
    private final SomeMapper someMapper; 
    public SomeDTO getById(Long id) {
        return this. someRepository //
                .findById(id) //
                .map(this. someMapper::mapToDto) //s
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RequestException("Entity not found Id");
    }
```

And unit test is:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeMapperImpl.class, OtherMapperImpl.class})
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeRepository someRepository;
    @Spy
    private SomeMapperImpl someMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeServiceImpl someService;

   @Test
    void testGetVorgangById_ValidId() {
        when(this.someRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(someObject));
        SomeDto someById = this.someService.getById(1L);
        ....
    }
}
```

I'm getting the exception because my repository mock doesn't return an object I want. I've tried to debug and compare objects using repository mock and mapper before calling service method and it works as it should. In a debugger I see that only the injected repository instance is not the one which should be injected, mapper instance is correct. Somehow Mockito inserts a new instance of my repository.

***EDIT***: Manual injection works correctly,

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  this.someService = new SomeService(someRepository, someMapper);
  ...
}
```

but @InjectMocks doesn't inject mocks as it should. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set up the some service at @BeforeEach injecting the mocks manually? Does this make any difference?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to instantiate service manually it works correctly. I just simply don't understand why @inectMocks doesn't inject mocks as it should.

Comment: IMHO I think that this is a problem between your `@SpringBootTest` annotation and `@InjectMocks` - when u use `@SpringBootTest` you need to use `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` instead of `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and `MockitoExtension` are incompatible. Either you want to autowire your components from your application context (`@SpringBootTest` with `@Autowired` and `@MockBean`) or you don't want to use the application context and manually inject your (mocked) collaborators (`MockitoExtension` with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76521923/injectmocks-injects-new-instance-instead-of-using-defined-mock#comment134923961_76521923).

In my case I had to manually inject all mocks beacuse `@SpringBootTest` and `MockitoExtention` are incompatible.

This code worked for me:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeMapperImpl .class})
class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeRepository someRepository;
    @Spy
    private SomeMapperImpl someMapper;

    private SomeService someService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.someService= new SomeServiceImpl (someRepository, someMapper);
    }
    @Test
    void testGetVorgangById_ValidId() {
        when(this.someRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(someObject));
        SomeDto someById = this.someService.getById(1L);
        ....
    }
}
```